Can I say this function is conservative on some region?
Let $F(x, y) = \frac{1-y}{x^2+(1-y)^2} \hat i + \frac{x}{x^2+(1-y)^2}\hat j$
Then $F$ is discontinuous at $(0, 1)$, so I will consider some curve C, and region D bounded by this curve that doesn't include $(0, 1)$ (ex $C: x^2 + y^2 = \frac{1}{4}$).
By Green's theorem, $\oint_{C} F \cdot dr = \iint_{D} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} dA = 0 $   $(\because \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 0)$
Then $\oint_C F \cdot dr = 0$ for any C in which there isn't $(0, 1)$, therefore F is path-independent for any path that lies on D.
As a result, can I say that '$F$ is conservative on any regions that dosen't include $(0, 1)$'?

Rather than say $F$ is "discontinuous" at $(0,1)$, let's say that $F$ is not defined at $(0,1)$ --- the domain of $F$ is $\mathbb R^2 - \{(0,1)\}$.
That domain $\mathbb R^2 - \{(0,1)\}$ does not include $(0,1)$, and so as a special case your question asks whether $F$ is conservative on $\mathbb R^2 - \{(0,1)\}$: in order to be conservative it is necessary that all circulation integrals of $F$ be equal to $0$.
But now you can check the integral of $F$ around a circle $C$ that surrounds $(0,1)$ is nonzero, for example the circle $C$ given by the equation $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$. Therefore, $F$ is not conservative on $\mathbb R^2 - \{(0,1)\}$.
One way you can correct this is to restrict yourself to simply connected regions, for which there is a nice theorem: if the vector field $F=\left<P,Q\right>$ is defined on a simply connected region, and if $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$, then $F$ is conservative.
Or, there's another theorem: for $F$ to be conservative on a region, it is sufficient that all circulation integrals of $F$ on that region be zero.
The general statement is that $F$ is not conservative on an open subset $D \subset \mathbb R - \{(0,1)\}$ if and only if there exists a Jordan curve $C \subset D$ such that that the inside of $C$ contains the point $(0,1)$: if $C$ exists then the circulation integral of $F$ around $C$ is nonzero, which can be proved by application of Green's Theorem; whereas if $C$ does not exist then, by a somewhat subtle topological argument, one can construct a potential function for $F$.
In your comment you ask about the example of the region $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid y < 0\}$. The vector field $F$ is indeed conservative on $D$. One proof is: $D$ is simply connected. Another proof is: for any Jordan curve $C \subset \mathbb R^2$ whose inside containe the point $(0,1)$, the curve $C$ must contain a point $(x,y)$ such that $y > 1$, and therefore $C \not \subset D$.

What I want to ask is whether F is path-independent for some region. I'm sorry to confuse you because I have used expression that 'any regions that dosen't include $(0, 1)$'. I wanted to ask whether I can say that F is conservative on regions like $ {(x, y) | x \in \mathbb{R}, y < 1} $ (that regions are setted arbitrarily), not regions that dosen't include $(0, 1)$ .

I have added a paragraph with a completely general criterion which, given a general region $D$, let's you determine whether $F$ is conservative on $D$. I have also applied the criteria in my answer to your requested example ${(x,y) \mid x \in \mathbb R, y < 1 }$. You can, if you desire, learn how to use this criterion on a region that is selected arbitrarily.

One thing you should keep in mind: if you select a region $D$ that does contain $(0,1)$, then $F$ is not conservative on $D$, for the simple reason that $F$ is not defined at every point of $D$. That is the reason for the importance and relevance of the expression 'any region that doesn't include $(0,1)$'.
